# Неправильно вывожу переменную JS, выводится как объект а это число

Tags: javascript, jquery, переменные

Корзина с кнопкой:

```js
var newprice, tovarid, allprice, price;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#cart > p').toggle(
    function() {
      $("#cart > div").show();
      $("#corner").attr("class", "corner-up");
    },
    function() {
      $("cart > div").hide();
      $("corner").attr("class", "corner-down");
    }
  );
  var newcount = 0;
  $('.add-tovar').click(function() {
    allprice = $('#cart span#price').attr("price");
    price = $(this).attr("price");
    tovarid = $(this).attr("rel");
    newprice = Number(allprice) + Number(price);
    newcount++;
    $('#cart span#price').html(newprice + ' руб. ').attr("price", newprice);
    $('#cart span.count').html(newcount);
  })

  $("#test").click(function(newprice) {
    $("#test2").html(Number(newprice) + " rub").attr("allprice", newprice);
  })
});

function tot() {
  console.log(newprice + " 111");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cart">
  <span>Моя корзина (<span class="count">0</span>) <span id="corner" class="corner-down"></span></span>

  <!--<span>Товаров: <span class="count">0</span></span>-->
  <span>На сумму: <span price="0" id="price">0</span></span>
  <span><a href="cart.html">Оформить</a></span>
</div>
<button id="test">test</button>
<p id="test2">something</p>
<button price="1500" rel="2" class="add-tovar">Добавить в корзину</button>
```

Требуется от кода вывести значение переменной, но выводится - `NaN`, `[object Object]`, `underfined`, короче все что угодно но не число. Число смог вывести просто в консоль для проверки через concole.log , там все ок.

**Как вывести переменную правильно и как перекинуть её же на другую страницу?**

И еще вопрос, как можно хранить вводимые данные пользователя в сессии?
Код написан для сайта-магазина, страница с корзиной.

Comment: Параметр анонимной функции-обработчика события клик - объект `event`, а не то, что Вы думаете (https://api.jquery.com/click/). Добавьте больше кода/html и объясните, откуда должно браться значение, которые Вы хотите вывести. На этом форуме рекомендуется ограничиваться одним вопросом на пост.

Comment: а куда выводится то ? ато я закинул ваш код в сниппет и там впринципе ничего никуда не выводится  )

Comment: В параграф с id="test2" (#test2), просто функция по кнопке запускается. Я не знаю как мне перенести значение переменной на другую страницу, это корзина, нужно перекинуть количество товара и цену на страницу оформления и там уже вывести как параграфы тоже.

Answer (score 0):

Параметр анонимной функции-обработчика события клик - объект `event`, а не то, что Вы думаете (https://api.jquery.com/click/).

```
$("#test").click(function(e) {
  $("#test2").html(newprice + " rub").attr("allprice", newprice);
});
```

Comment: Блин вот сейчас перечитал и понял о чем Вы, а так с лету и не разобрался, полез читать ссылку. 
Спасибо большое, задачкой меньше.
Осталось на другую страницу вывести данные.

Comment: @ВладиславДементьев Задайте об этом отдельный вопрос.